# using preg_match to validate date dd-MON-yyyy

Tags: php, regex, validation, preg-match

I am trying to validate a date in the following format 20 May 2019
I am not able to get this right. I have tested the day and year and they work fine, the problem is with my MONTH ([a-z]) code. Any suggestions on being able to validate the month as a name and not number

```
<?php
   $date = "28-may-2019";
   if (preg_match('/^([0-9]{1,2})-([a-z])-([0-9]{4})$/',$date)){
       echo "Format is correct";
    }else{
        echo "Format is not correct!";
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: `([a-z]+)` or `([A-Za-z]+)`

Comment: You may want to also look into using `strtotime()` as a compliment or possibly as an alternative to regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[a-z]+

add additional sign ,more than one characters